# Proxy to verify correct http traffic?

Tags: linux, http

I have a two processes that communicate via HTTP and I somehow suspect there is a concurrency issue that is occurring with very high volume traffic. Due to the high volume of traffic, logging the traffic in itself is quite useless. Ideally, I'd be looking for some kind of proxy that verifies the correctness of the http traffic at the protocol level (i.e. correct Content-lengths etc). Does such a proxy exist ? I'm on linux

Answer (score 0):

The only linux proxy you need is [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org). By default squid sanitizes your traffic and it runs on most distributions.

GL